# Usual plant Qs: what, how, when etc

Tags: identification, houseplants, repotting, potting-soil, support

What plant is this? How do I care for it? Placement, watering, feeding, pruning...

I was given this plant when somebody left the country. It seems happy enough. As you can see it's gone native! But the support is very loose. I'd like to repot. But how? Can I trim it? Take cuttings and start again? What compost/soil do I buy? Where do I get the support? How do I pin it (where to get pins)? etcetera etcetara etcetera.

All thoughts welcome. Thank you.

Housepalnt:
[image: Houseplant]

Out of Contol!
[image: Plant out of control]

Leaf shape
[image: houseplant leafe shape]

Where would I take a cutting?
[image: Where would I take a cutting?]

Where to get pins, support, soil?
[image: houseplant pinned]

Answer (score 1):

That’s a beautiful plant! It looks like a very healthy **pothos** vine. Luckily, it’s a very hearty plant, and easy to care for.

[This is a great article about pothos care](https://www.thespruce.com/pothos-an-easy-to-grow-houseplant-1403154), but I’ll sum up some of the points here:

- Pothos like bright, indirect light, but they tolerate almost any type of light. They popular vines in offices and other low light areas. Some types of pothos will develop more variation (yellow/white coloring) if given more light.
- Water moderately, about once per week during active growth periods, less in the winter. They can tolerate not being watered if your away for a few weeks though. Basically, let the soil totally dry out between watering.
- Take trimmings if you feel a vine is too long, or if it’s getting leggy. Just cut at a node (the bump near a leaf - that node will grow a new root system. (The article I liked has more details on pothos propagation.)
- Any well-draining house plant soil will work just fine for a Pothos.

I’ve never personally seen a pothos pinned up to a stake like this one, but it looks cool and doesn’t hurt it at all. (My pothos is on top of a bookshelf and I let it trail down the sides.)

To repot it, I’m not sure if you will want to unpin the vines from the support or not, it will just depend on what is easier for you. Otherwise, the goal will be to “tip” the root system out of the original pot, and place it in a new pot, topping it off with new soil.

You can find supports, pots, soil, and pins at any gardening store. Many hardware stores like Lowe’s have garden sections.

Good luck with your new plant!

Comment: That's great! Thank you. I can now decide what to do. It looks like a quick trim, a repot or a new plant from cutting are all possible!